# yii2 upload file to database

Tags: database, file-upload, yii2

I would like to attach an uploaded file (pdf) to a normal create function, but it doesn't really work. I have model, controller, form modified, and it says uploading, model validates, but still, no pdf in db. I have set field as blob. what can be wrong?

model:

```
use yii\web\UploadedFile;
class MyModel extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord {

public $file;
...

public function rules() {
    return [
        [['file'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => true, 'extensions' => 'pdf'],
...
```

_form:

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'enableClientValidation' => false,
    'options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'],
    ]
...
<?= $form->field($model, 'file')->fileInput() ?>
```

controller:

```
use yii\web\UploadedFile;
public function actionCreate() {
    $model = new MyModel;

    try {
        if ($model->load($_POST)) {
            $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');

            if ($model->save()) {
...
```

Comment: Can you add the code you are using? View, Controller and Model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it works for file uploading

```
$model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');//Get the uploaded file

$model->file->saveAs('uploads/' . $model->file->name);//Save uploaded file at your desired location

$user->image = $model->file->name;//image is my database field name,to only save the name of the uploaded file
```

I hope this will make it clear and solve your problem